# How to get data from JWT token and keep requesting it on Client? .Net Core

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I have setup a Web Api in .Net Core 2.2 for authentication using JWT.

I'm using postman for testing and i am able to send

http://localhost:5000/api/account/login

```
{
    "Username" : "fred",
    "Password" : "123"
}
```

and the response

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiIxIiwicm9sZSI6IkFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTM0NjUxMTgsImV4cCI6MTU1MzQ2NTcxOCwiaWF0IjoxNTUzNDY1MTE4fQ.YF0ztM_p9N2UMUJKYTjJHpkvtJwVymhtOy5H5g2qOSs
```

My problem is, how do i keep the user authenticated and retrieve the data on the Client?

I have this little App in .Net 4.5

User logs in and username and password are sent to web api and return the token.
How and when am i suppose to send the token back to the APi to validate it?

Comment: What is your client? Is it angular or MVC? For web api, it is stateless, for accessing security resource, you need to append the token with bearer in your request. For validating the token, this is implemented by `app.UseAuthentication();`. Check this doc [ASP.NET Core 2.2 - JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)

Answer (score 1):

When I create a token using JWT for an api and want to test using it in Postman, the Header needs to have the word "Bearer" in front of the token.  So for example, you want to retrieve data (Client) so its a Post method with the Header **Key**: Authorization  **Value**: Bearer (Your Token)cut and paste your token with space behind "Bearer".

Answer (score 0):

This flow might help you. This is just a pseudo code.

User logs in from client side. You redirect to home page after saving token in local storage.

```
http.post("mysite.me/api/token", userCredentialsDto).subscribe(token => {
    localstorage.save(token);
    redirectTo["/home"];
});
```

The request goes to TokenController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(UserCredentialsDto userCreds)
{
    _validationService.validate(userCreds);
    return _jwtService.CreateToken(userCreds);
}
```

When you go to home page or whatever page you want, **you can get the access token form your local storage attach that token to each requests header before sending it to the server**.

The thing to note here is that, **the access token is what authenticates the user so, util your access token expires your user is authenticated**. Once the access token expires, you can user the refresh token to refresh your token and continue using you app.

JWT is base64 encoded. You can easily decode it in client side. **Also .Net core automatically binds the JWT claims to HttpContext.User object, after successful authentication**.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to send the token in your request that point to your protected api's endpoints with the [Authorize] tag. On the other hand, those endpoints that do not have that tag or that have the [AllowAnonymous] tag are not necessary to send the token.

On how to send them depends on what client technology you are using, but the principle is the same. Before you send any request to the server from the client you need to add a Bearer token to your header of your http client requests. This is an example of how your client should send the http request to the server:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:7161/api/appserviceprovider' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIyIiwibmFtZSI6Ikpvc2UiLCJlbWFpbCI6Impvc2VhcEBkZXYuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6IkFkbWlubfN0cmF0b3IiLCJuYmYiOjE2NzY0NDk5NjgsImV4cCI6MTY3NzA1NDc2OCwiaWF0IjoxNjc2NDQ5OTY4fQ.bfwdl8G_tT8MFKud9LRyVosqnpoth0mGbkQacmDOhBNwIDEQd1eaUIaDLMTBdwijLT9UeI2Jqn8-Kdo60MqFIw' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "healthCareCenterName": "House Senior heaven TLL",
  "street": "High Rocks #34",
  "city": "Gold Cost",
  "postcode": "3453",
  "firstName": "Adam",
  "lastName": "Sandler",
  "auStateId": 1,
  "phoneNumber": "6543564323",
  "mobile": "76787643299",
  "email": "adams@outlook.com",
  "website": "https://iamadansandler.com.au",
  "createdByUser": 0,
  "modifiedByUser":0
}'
```

This is a basic example of how to add it on angular v14:

```
public getAvancePresupuestal(filtro: AvancePresupuestalFiltro, token: string): Observable<AvancePresupuestalTable[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    });
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/avance`;
    return this.http.post<AvancePresupuestalTable[]>(url, filtro, {headers});
}
```

On Postman you can simply select the tab Authorization, select the Bearer Token type and then paste your token on its field.